# Is it possible to create a mobile App from ashx files

Tags: mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile, extjs, coronasdk

We have a mobileweb application that is written in ASP.NET (.ashx files) with Jquery. Is it possible to convert it into a native app using either Phonegap, Corona or similar platforms?

Answer (score 0):

You could, but you may need to restructure your app.

- PhoneGap (or one of the others) can load a framework starting page which is wrapped as a native app.
- Inside your framework starting page, you can link to your `.ashx` file to download more jQuery-Mobile  pages and data.